# Run a python code every 00 seconds on the clock (python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

How would you run a code when the clock turns to 00 seconds in python? (12:31:00, 13:24:00,.. HH:MM:00) I am using a rpi, so when 00 seconds strikes, the code will print something, else wait.

My idea for the code is.. But my formatting is wrong. Thank you!

```
while True:
    if datetime == HH:MM:00
      print format(datetime.datetime.now())

    else 
      wait
```

Comment: [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/) can do it, if you'd like to avoid using cron or making your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

Time till the end of the current minute can be computed:

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(60.0 - now.second - now.microsecond / 1e6)
    # do the work
```